# rails heroku deployment troubleshooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

So I created a heroku app, pushed it up, db:migrate it already. The app works fine on my local machine, but it just crashes on heroku. I'm a newbie and don't know where to start trouble-shooting this. Thanks in advance! All the logs from creating the app to migration are here:

```
2011-04-17T22:51:03-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                             .paginate(:page => params[:page...
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:                               ^
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-04-18T05:51:07+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-04-17T22:51:07-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-04-17T22:51:07-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-04-17T22:51:07-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-04-17T22:51:10-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]: ...                             .paginate(:page => params[:page...
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:                               ^
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:346:in `require_or_load'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `new'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:63:in `map'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `new'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-04-18T05:51:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-04-17T22:51:15-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-04-18T05:51:21+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET indelearn.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-17T22:51:22-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 75.72.164.255 | 795 | http | 503
2011-04-18T05:51:22+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET indelearn.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-17T22:51:22-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 75.72.164.255 | 795 | http | 503
2011-04-17T22:51:39-07:00 heroku[rake.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-04-17T22:51:43-07:00 heroku[rake.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-04-17T22:51:49-07:00 heroku[rake.1]: State changed from up to complete
2011-04-18T05:51:59+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET indelearn.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-17T22:51:59-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 75.72.164.255 | 795 | http | 503
2011-04-18T05:51:59+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET indelearn.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-17T22:51:59-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 75.72.164.255 | 795 | http | 503
2011-04-18T05:52:00+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET indelearn.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-17T22:52:00-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 75.72.164.255 | 795 | http | 503
2011-04-18T05:52:01+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET indelearn.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-17T22:52:01-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 75.72.164.255 | 795 | http | 503
```

The users_contoller #28 is a paginate followed by a really long sql query:

```
@discussions = Discussion.find_by_sql("SELECT d.*, MAX(c.created_at) AS lastCommentTime 
                 FROM discussions d JOIN comments c ON d.id = c.commentable_id 
                 WHERE c.commentable_type = 'Discussion' AND c.user_id = #{@user.id} 
                 GROUP BY d.id ORDER BY lastCommentTime DESC")
                 .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

So I've deleted the line-break before the dot and it is fixed. Thanks for you guys' superpowers! It's so hard for a newbie to spot the critical error line in that log file. :)

Comment: Can you update your question to include your `users_controller.rb`?

Comment: Glad you found your problem! Learning to read stack traces effectively is probably the most important skill I've developed (which probably says not-so-good things about my programming). :)

Comment: there should be a book about rails debugging patterns. :) maybe there already are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace mentions `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` at line 28. What is the code at and around this file? That is likely where you'll find your issue.

Also, I know it sounds silly, but triple-check that everything is checked in to your Git repo. Since Heroku is Git-based, it's easy to forget to check something in, and `git push` an old version of your app to the server.